# Calculate bitwise 64bit operations on 32bit system with PHP

Tags: php, algorithm, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I have a series of base 10 representations of binary numbers stored in a database. for example:

```
686316060672
```

Now i have written some simple code to extract the bits from this:

```
$code = 686316060672;

for($n = 0; $n < 64; $n++)
{
    $r = pow(2,$n);

    if(($code  & $r) > 0)
    {
        printf('n=%d'."\n", $n);
    }
}
```

Now i know this number in binary is larger than 32bit, and thus im not getting the results i would expect.

the above code gives me:

```
n=21 n=23 n=24 n=25 n=27 n=30
```

when i know the answer should be:

```
n=21 n=23 n=24 n=25 n=27 n=30 n=31 n=32 n=33 n=34 n=35 n=36 n=39
```

it would seem that its a 32bit operating system issue, but for i cant seem to work out how to split the `$code` value into two 32 bit segments.

this is what i tried:

```
$number =  base_convert($code, 10, 2);
$lsb = bindec(substr($number, -32));
$msb = bindec(substr_replace($number, '', -33));
```

I then replace `$code` with `$lsb` and `$msb`

can someone point me in the right direction so that i can get all the values for n.

Comment: You won't be able to split the number apart as a normal integer in PHP, because it's already too late - PHP would need to hold the 64-bit number for you to split, and if it could do that, you wouldn't need to split it. You might be able to use the [BCMath](http://php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php) or [GMP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.gmp.php) extensions, which can handle arbitrarily large numbers.

Comment: any chance of giving me an example @IMSoP ? im having a read of both of those extensions now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after looking into ita bit more.. i was looking at the problem the wrong way. below is how i solved the problem.

```
$x = 686316060672;
$y = 2;


for($n = 1; $n < 65; $n++){
$x = floor($x / $y); 
if($x % 2){
printf('n=%d'."\n", $n);
}// end if

}// end for
```

this gives:

```
n=21 n=23 n=24 n=25 n=27 n=30 n=31 n=32 n=33 n=34 n=35 n=36 n=39
```